# Missing ";" before 'namespace' and ";" before 'using'

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, namespaces, iostream

So I am working on a program that is due tomorrow and for some reason I keep getting this 2 errors, if I click on the first one it takes me to the iostream file and right before the _STD_BEGIN it wants me to put ";" but if I do that it messes up the file in the library so I am pretty sure I do not have to do that, the second error is in my main.cpp and it points to using namespace std; and it wants me to put a ";" before it =, if I do so the error disappears and it keeps pointing at the iostream error....
I have no idea what to do and my deadline is tomorrow.
This is my main.cpp include section with the modification to using namespace std

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Package.h"
;using namespace std;
```

Comment: I suppose you forgot to post your code. Anyway, the error is in `Package.h`

Comment: remove that semicolon before using namespace std and find the missing semicolon in your package header file.

Comment: So I found the mission semicolon but now I get a linker error...

Comment: Post a new question then, if you can't figure out your linker error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for a `class` or `struct` definition in `Package.h` that's missing its semicolon.  ie.

```
class act
{
    // yadda
}  // no semicolon here
```

Then add the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

When you get a "missing ;`type error on a line that follows closeley behind a bunch of`#include`statements, the likely culprit is a missing`;` in one of the header files.  To find out which, start at the last include file, Package.h.  You'll surely find a missing semicolon there.  It's probably missing after a class declaration, as if you had written:

```
class Foo
{
}
```

instead of

```
class Foo
{
};
```